# Bitcoin payment gateways in c#

Tags: c#, nbitcoin, qbitninja

My question is about Bitcoin payment gateways and we can add their gateways to my site Like those sites (bitpay.com,https://gourl.io/), I want to create a bitcoin payment gateway in C#

my question :

If two users paid from their wallet at the same time and at the same price (Bitcoin wallet address) but one of those payments was confirmed, how can I find out which transaction is for which user?

I can see the payments that came to my wallet with this code, but how do I know which user has made which payment?

```
QBitNinjaClient client = new QBitNinjaClient(_network);
        var _walletAddress = BitcoinAddress.Create(walletAddress, _network);
        var balance = client.GetBalance(_walletAddress, true).Result;

        foreach (var operation in balance.Operations)
        {
            
                if (operation.Confirmations > 0)
                    
                    {
                       //do
                    }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try btcpayserver.org

Comment: @Jannes I want to create a payment getway too and like this but what is my question answare?